# Getting different results running script and by shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm currently having a problem when I run a script that I wrote to tell if two texts files are identical:

```
a="MyOut1.txt"
b="out1.txt"
f1=open(a,'r')
f2=open(b,'r')
l1=f1.readlines()
l2=f2.readlines()
f1.close()
f2.close()
print(l2==l1)
```

When I run the code via terminal I get a False result (even though I expect the files to be the same) and when I run it through python shell it gives me True as you can see:

[image]

Comment: Try `print(f1)` and `print(f1)` you will see some difference.

Comment: Print both `l1` and `l2` and see if they are the same in both of the programs.

Comment: Did you check if the command `python` is linked to same interpreter (Python 3.6.3) as your python shell

Comment: Please don't link to images of character-based output. Just put the text in the post and [format it accordingly using markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First of all

Are you 100% sure that both files are the same.  Also are you sure that the script you wrote is exactly the same as the lines shown in the picture.  Lastly double check if python sees the files as the same do as Simon suggested and `print(l1)` and `print(l2)`.

### Suggestion

A much quicker way to read from the files and test if they are the same is.

`l1 = open("one.txt", "r").read()
l2 = open("two.txt", "r").read()
print(l2 == l2)`

Comment: as long as simon meant to print(f1) (the file) its just giving me the name of the file, the status and the location in the memory.
if u guys meant to print the lines its actually helped me understand the reason why they arent identical. I posted an answer with another question

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why the texts are'nt identical but I still need an answer why its happening:
when i print the content of both of the texts it's identical, but when I print it as a list, it seems that 1 of the texts contain \r right before every \n.

```
>>> 
>>> l1[10]
'\n'
>>> l2[10]
'\r'
>>> l2[11]
'\n'
```

this happen every time when i got \n in the text.
my following question is:
a) why its happening?
b) i just need an option to compare the contents of the texts. is there a way to do it better?

Comment: This is due to Windows adding "\r\n" to every line ending opposed to "\n" on unix.  This can be avoided by using program such as dos2unix which can be installed with sudo apt install dos2unix then run dos2unix on both one.txt and two.txt